# User-Agent header cannot be removed in jodd-http

Tags: jodd

I want to send a request without User-Agent for testing purposes. I tried to use `headerRemove` but it doesn't work. Is there a way to achieve this?

```kotlin
val request = HttpRequest.get("https://example.com")
                         .header("x-dummy-header", "remove me")

headerRemove("x-dummy-header")
headerRemove("User-Agent")
```

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Connection: Close
Host: example.com
User-Agent: Jodd HTTP
```

Comment: Please that a look at the updated answer, had to preserve the default user agent because of the other teams, still, fixed you issue:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed in `v6.2.0` (just released:). Jodd Http used to have a default User-Agent, which was set if no such header was present.

Now you can do one of the two things:

1. Remove default headers in `HttpBase.Defaults.headers` - its a map of default headers loaded in every instance of `HttpRequest`
2. Simply remove it from the `HttpRequest` using `headerRemove()` method or remove all default headers (there is just that one) with the `headersClean()` method.